# Fetch contacts related to Household

Tags: soql

I am using the npsp and I have this installed Household package with the object npo02__Household__c. The npo02__Household__c can have many contacts associated with it. So I figured I could just do a simple relationship lookup:

```
Select Id, (Select Id from Contacts) from  npo02__Household__c
```

but this is telling me that this relationship does not exist.

Is there any way I can figure out the proper naming for this, or if it is even possible to run this type of query?

Comment: `Contacts` is an OOB relationship name between Account and Contacts; for a package, the relationship name will end in `__r` but the actual name will need to be discovered via Workbench or the Force.com UI (inspect Contact object and find relevant lookup field)

Comment: It says the child relationship name is Contacts and I tried that, along with Contacts__r, but I get the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the namespace. It should be `npo02__Contacts__r`. The Child Relationship Name field doesn't include the namespace or the __r, so you need to remember to add those in, as necessary.

```
Select Id, (Select Id from npo02__Contacts__r) from npo02__Household__c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always find the *verbatim* relationship name using:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.np02__Household__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == Contact.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```